# Generator of inertia group in function field extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, laurent-series

Can Someone help me solve the following problem?

> Let C((T)) be the field of formal Laurent series in the variable T over an algebraically closed field
>   C of characteristic $0$.
>
> (1) Prove that the algebraic closure of C((T)) is $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}$ C(($T^{1/n}$)) and deduce that for any $n \ge 1$,
>   the field C((T)) has a unique extension of degree $n$.
>
> (2) Let $f(X) \in C[X]$ be a polynomial such that
>   $f(X) = \prod_{i=1}^{r}(X-\alpha_{i})^{e^{i}}$
>   with $\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_r \in C$ distinct and $e_1, \dots , e_r \ge 1$. Prove that the inertia group of $F(T, X) =
> f(X)−T$ over C(T) at the prime T is generated by a permutation $\sigma$ of cycle type $(e_1, \dots , e_r)$.
>
> (3) Give a counterexample to (2) when C is of positive characteristic $p$ (one must have $p \mid e_i$
>   for some $i$).

**Edit:**

This is my outcome so far

(1) Found a proof [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Puiseux+series#Puiseux)

(2) I think it somehow related to the fact that the decomposition group is isomorphic to the Galois group of the completion: $D(Q/P) \cong Gal(L_Q | K_P)$.   And that the $D(Q/P) = I(Q/P)$ since $\bar{K_P}$ is algebraically closed.

(3) Haven't found anything yet

Comment: Is this homework? Have you done anything yet? Have you had any insights so far?

Comment: Yes, edited just now.

Comment: For 2), given such a polynomial, you see that the degree of the field extension is $m= lcm(e_1, \ldots e_r).$ You want to know how the polynomial factors into irreducible polynomials. Factor the reduction modulo $T,$ and then use Hensl’s lemma to lift this factorization, and you have your claimed cycle decomposition.

Comment: For 3), you want a polynomial where you can not apply Hensel’s lemma. For example, choose an appropriate polynomial that is not separable.

Comment: @Dedalus i need a separable example

Comment: @Dedalus how can I show that the degree is $m$

Comment: For 3), my advice is to go with the same idea as I stated before. It should not be hard (I think) once you know the general idea. Try with some polynomials where one factor is divisible by $p$ and see what you can get. I have not checked this extensively myself so I might be wrong.

Comment: @Joshfisher You can also use monodromy to find the answer to 2).

Comment: @Dedalus How can I know for sure that $\sigma$ is permuting the roots and not fixing them?

Comment: @Joshfisher You are right, I should think a bit more before I post. But what I say can be fixed. You know that $\sigma$ permutes the roots of $f(T,X).$ By Hensel's lemma, $f(T,X)$ splits as a product into $r$ irreducible polynomials, call the $i$th polynomial $P_i.$ Then you know that it has degree $e_i.$ You want to prove that $\sigma$ can not switch roots between the different $P_i$'s.

Comment: @Dedalus yes, but how can i show that $P_i$ is irreducible?

Comment: @Joshfisher Suppose to the contrary that $P_i$ is not irreducible. Then $P_i = Q_iR_i$ with $Q_i,R_i$ relatively prime (meaning that they have no common prime factors). Thus you can write $a Q_i+bR_i=1$ for some polynomials $a$ and $b.$ Reduce this equation mod $T,$ and you get something absurd, basically saying that you can find a polynomial $A$ in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $A*(X-\alpha_i)^{e_i}=1.$ But you know that $(X-\alpha_i)^{e_i}$is not a unit in $\mathbb{C}[X].$

Comment: So basically all follows from Hensel's lemma. As I also said, you can use monodromy if you wish as well.

Comment: I also want to say that it is good that you question the arguments!

Comment: @Dedalus i'm not so familiar with monodromy.

Comment: Well, then no need for it if you agree with the argument I gave.

Comment: @Dedalus in your proof what if $P_i = (x-\beta_i)^{e_i}$ ? (with $\bar{\beta_i} =\alpha_i$)

Comment: Your polynomial is separable, since $F'(T,X)$and $F(T,X)$ are relatively prime. This means that there are no repeated roots, so your case can not occur.

Comment: @Dedalus (3) I'm trying to compute the inertia group for $x^{p+1}-x-t$  i think it might be related to Artin–Schreier theory but i'm not sure. Any idea how to continue?

Comment: @Joshfisher What field are you working over now? A field of characteristic $p>0$ I assume?

Comment: @Dedalus yes, exactly.

Comment: @Joshfisher I am not sure, but I think that in the case $x^{p+1}-x-t$ the inertia group is cyclic of order $p$. That's because the Galois group at the completion at $(t)$ is isomorphic to the intertia group, and by Hensel's lemma the order of the Galois extension is bounded above by $p$. On the other hand looking for the ramification in $C(t)[x]/(x^{p+1}-x-t)$ we get that the ramification is at least $p$.

Comment: I might be wrong here (did not try to prove it) but I think that this work to show that the size is OK. Maybe the direction is to look for a non-cyclic inertia group.

Comment: @Madarb You are correct.
Joshfisher  What is needed is to find, for example, an extension with wild non-cyclic ramification, as Madarb points out.

Comment: @Dedalus There is a theorem: any Galois extension of K of degree p equal to the characteristic of K is the splitting field of an Artin–Schreier polynomial. in my example the polynomial is not Artin–Schreier.

Comment: Well, once again, apply Hensel's lemma to see that the polynomial splits as $g(x)h(X)$ with $g$ of degree $1,$and $h(x)$ of degree $p.$ So the splitting field is of the polynomial $h(x),$ which is of degree $p.$ So this does not rule out that $h(x)$ is an Artin-Schreier polynomial.

Comment: @Madarb do you have any idea for such polynomial?

Comment: @Dedalus we have that h(x) is indeed an Artin-Schreier by the theorem. On the other hand, looking at h under reduction module T it can't be an Artin-Schreier

Comment: Anyhow, I think we have specified what you need to do: Find a polynomial such that the Galois group is not cyclic. To get you started, consider a polynomial, such as $(x-1)^p(x+1)^p*x-T$ (I assume that the characteristic is not $2$). Is the Galois group of this polynomial cyclic? If so, is it of cycle type $(p,p,1)?$

Comment: Joshfisher No idea, actually. Dedalus' idea looks good though.
@Dedalus I am not the OP, but I'm certainly interested in this. I understand how to compute local Galois groups in $0$ characteristic, since there is not much to compute. But here how would you do it? Can you kindly give any tips/hints? I'm not even sure how to factor this specific polynomial over the completion (not even in the very specific example $p=3$)

Comment: @Madrab i'm toatlly in the exact position. How one can compute the galios group of such extension?

Comment: @Dedalus i would like you give me some directions..

Comment: @Dedalus I know, i'm trying to use this to give the answer to (3). I want to prove that any extension of $K((T))$ with degree $p^n$ has an  Artin-Schreier form and thus is not cylic.

Comment: @Joshfisher It is not true that any extension with degree $p^n$ has Artin-Schreier form! There are cyclic extensions of degree $p^n!$ They are given by higher order Witt polynomials.

Comment: @Dedalus I'm not so familiar with Witt polynomials . But isn't it true for extensions with the form of the above question ?

Comment: For some more unsolicited advice I would recommend you to try to understand the answers that have been given to you in full detail before posting more questions.

Comment: I just wanted to inform you that the polynomial $x^p-x-t$ is reducible, so I would suggest you continue with the example I gave.

Comment: @Dedalus do you have a proof it works ?

Comment: No, and I think, with some computation that the Galoos group for the polynomial is cyclic, though I am not sure.

Comment: @Dedalus What about $x^{p^2}(x-1)-t$ ?

Comment: Would you mind saying where this problem is from?

Comment: I don't know, it's from my homework..

Comment: I now know how to produce a non-cyclic extension, I think. I will try to write it up tomorrow after I have thought about it.

Comment: @Dedalus great! looking forward for your answer

Comment: Nevermind, it did not work out unfortunately.

Comment: @Joshfisher Are you sure that you can not provide just an inseparable polynomial? Given how you worded the question, it seems as if that should be allowable.

Comment: I would recommend that you ask this question on Mathoverflow. Just ask the third, and give context.